# Pagespeed rewrite_javascript everything except 1 single js file

Tags: javascript, nginx, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have a small issue with `rewrite_javascript` module which minify JS file. This function is awesome since pagespeed also generate a new URL for everyfile if we purge the cache, thus enable us to use Cloudfront cache easily with pagespeed's `ShardDomain`

However I encounter an issue with one of my file `/js/min/app/common.js"` which doesn't get rewrite at all despite the file under it has been rewrite.

[image]

I just don't get the idea why this could be happening.

Are there anyone have the same issue and found a solution?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for the time it takes for this question. I post here the details of my pagespeed configuration:

In HTTP block, I have:

```
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
pagespeed PreserveUrlRelativity on;
pagespeed ForceCaching on;
pagespeed InPlaceRewriteDeadlineMs 100;

pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_meta_tags;
pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css,sprite_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;

pagespeed GlobalStatisticsPath /pagespeed_global_statistics;
pagespeed GlobalAdminPath /pagespeed;
pagespeed EnableCachePurge on;
```

Comment: It is difficult to help you without a copy of your nginx config fie showing all        pagespeed filters.

Comment: Can you post the content of common.js? Pagespeed by default won't rewrite "introspective" JS files, perhaps you've got content inside common.js that flags it as "non-rewriteable".

Comment: @JoshKG I tried to remove several configuration and still not able to find what cause the problem

Comment: Can you show common.js?

Comment: @JoshKG here you go: https://labelleassiette.fr/js/min/app/common.js . It is minified though. I could not find the detaiils on what are the flags by pagespeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Pagespeed will not rewrite JavaScript files that are considered "introspective". If you read [the Pagespeed docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify?hl=en#risks) it states:

> ...a JavaScript file that calls document.getElementsByTagName('script') will not be rewritten

Looking into your common.js file, there are lines which include the function call `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`. This is why Pagespeed will not rewrite the file.

If you want to disable this Pagespeed check, in your nginx config, add this line:

```
pagespeed AvoidRenamingIntrospectiveJavascript off;
```

More info in the [Pagespeed docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls#aris).

Comment: I tried with the directive but it seems like pagespeed is way stricter. So i am gonna try moving any parts contains `document.getElementsByTagName('script').` out of common.js

Comment: The anwser is that I was bundling require.js and jquery into my common.js. The problem is that even with `AvoidRenamingIntrospectiveJavascript` turned off, pagespeed still enforce this rule. What I did was move the static scripts into one file and the rest move to another file. The js file contain bundle of jquery and require.js. To improve caching I upload this to s3 and send serve by cloudfront.